# How to sort photos in Swift based on date added to gallery

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

My app has a requirement where photos are loaded from iPhone gallery and listed in the app. Currently the sort order is based on `PHAsset creationDate` property. I would like to know how we can sort the assets based on the date added as how we see in All photos on iPhone.

I could see that `PHAsset` properties `creationDate`, `modificationDate` and other dates(listed below) from `PhAsset` metadata are the same, which is the date taken of the photo.

1. DateTime
2. DateTimeDigitized
3. DateTimeOriginal

Is there a way to get the date added for a `PHAsset`?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [PHFetchOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions?language=objc) you would end up doing something like this

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
let sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = sortOrder
```

Comment: Hi Hady,Thanks for your reply. This is what I am currently doing which will sort based on creationDate. I am checking for an option to sort based on the date added to iPhone gallery.

Comment: hmm I am not sure but have you tried using "date" only, I remember vaguely that's the key for the date of addition

Comment: Hi Hady, "Date" is not a supported sort descriptor in fetch options